# Meaning of "しとーば"

Tags: meaning, dialects

Context: Character introduced himself as a baseball player part of the 二軍 team then says:

> 野球選手ちゅうても、筋トレしすぎてケガ**しとーば**、１軍に上がったことはないがや

I assume it's some kind of dialect but I was not able to find what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

がや should be part of [Nagoya dialect](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/t/a/%E5%90%8D%E5%8F%A4%E5%B1%8B%E5%BC%81)  and is an ending particle used to describe a surprise or claim.

Thanks to the comment,

> `So, I reckon しとーば should be a 名古屋弁{なごやべん}.`

this doesn't seem to be correct. However, there does seem to be a similar variant used in Kumamoto dialect [ばい](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/dialect/3394/m0u/) as well as in Gunma dialect [ばい](https://twitter.com/johshu_ben/status/1087534908346716160).

I guess it means しているので (Kumamoto) or してばかり（Gunma) in your contexts.

ちゅうても　is also a dialect-ish phrase for といっても, but I think it's pretty common even in Kanto (not only in Nagoya).

I think

> 野球選手といっても、筋トレしすぎてケガしているので、１軍に上がったことはないんだ。

> *Even if he is a professional baseball player, he has never played for the first team due to an injury from excessive muscle training. (Somewhat blaming in a way).*

is standard Japanese.

Comment: Has a silent down-voter come back finally???　つい最近の署名運動みたいじゃん。秘書がやりました。

Comment: I don't know if it helps but apparently it is one of the character's quirks that he speaks in a mishmash of a bunch of different dialects.

Comment: @xndrr So, is しとーば  a variant or typo or author's choice of the ending particle? I think しとーばい seems a Kyushu dialect. It changes just the location from Nagoya to Kyushu and does not change meaning.